# Best way to structure streamed data with missing table fields to benefit filesize

Tags: sql

I currently have a service which provides live data every second in JSON format and I save it to a SQLserver table.

Typically the table is approx 20 fields of varchar, int and decimal and each row/record is a single timestamp for each second. Both the JSON and INSERT query contain data for all fields on every timestamp.

In order to speed up response times and reduce transmitted bytes, the JSON in future will only contain changes to the data (ie the value is different from the previous value), so many fields will not be contained in the JSON.

My question is what is the best way to store this in SQL to also benefit from the reduction in data - Is there a better way to do this? If I used the same table structure with NULL entries then surely this will be the same byte size based on the field type anyway?

Edit: The new streaming format would mean the following

- Each timeframe will still have data values but they would not be in the JSON array if there was no data change from previous values.
- I'm looking at saving disk space. I'm happy to rebuild the data when required with post processing outside of SQL to get 'full' data for any particular timestamp.
- Possibly it might be better to just store the full JSON response string with timestamp?

Comment: My main focus was ability to benefit from reduced storage size of knowing that the current data is the same as previous data without storing the same values repeated.

Comment: How often does the data change?  How is the data being queried?  The second question is particularly important.  The structure of databases should be (at least partly) based on *how* the data will be used.

Comment: Typically say over 24 hours then every field would change on every refresh for approx 3 hours and the remaining 21 hours have very few changes. The data is being queried in C# and R as an entire day (rather than record by record) for analysis but queried speed is not so important, there is a lot of data so my priority is saving space. Also, just found this which may be interesting https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jocapc/2015/05/16/json-support-in-sql-server-2016/

Comment: I do need to know the current value though even though data is not provided on that timeframe

Comment: Does SQLServer have a data compression option?  This would be a good use case for it, since your data has a lot of repeated values.  You wouldn't need to change anything else other than enabling the compression.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with JSON and the whole idea, but the best way to store possible NULLs is to put fixed size fields (INT, BIT, SMALL INT DECIMAL, FLOAT, Etc.) in the beginning of a table and variable sized fields (VARCHAR, NVARCHAR, XML, JSON etc.) at the end of your table.

Second advice would be to use temporal table update in SQL 2016. That will store the data maybe in the best way (needs a research), but will significantly make easy extraction and handling the data.